# Handling ?aspxerrorpath=<script

Tags: asp.net

I have an issue where adding this to any asp.net request causes and unhandled error (regardless of CustomErrors setting): `?aspxerrorpath=<script`

The weird thing is that I have two applications that are totally immune to the problem, but I can't spot the difference. I'm running on IIS 7 and using the 4.0 Framework. But this also happens on my 3.5 IIS 6 apps. Again, I have two sites that are fine (IIS 7, 4.0) but can't determine why. I have tried turning off request validation to no avail. Has anyone encountered something similar?

**FIXED:**
This looks like it was an Umbraco issue. It was ignoring my validateRequest="false" in the web.config. Adding this to the template fixed it:

```
<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Since I have custom errors on I get the generic yellow screen. If I turn that off I get an error telling me that a potentially dangerous Request.QueryString was detected. I've tried turning off request validation and I've also tried <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />, but I get the same result either way.

Comment: If you have fixed your problem you should add an answer and accept it yourself

Comment: I am. The system required me to wait 8 hours to post and now 2 days to accept.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it was an Umbraco issue. It was ignoring my validateRequest="false" in the web.config.

Adding this to the template fixed it:

```
<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your  section, ensure the following is set:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Comment: This is the problem. That attribute is being ignored. It looks like it was an umbraco issue. Adding this to a template fixed it: <umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>